# Crash due to unrecognised selector on MKPointAnnotation

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkclusterannotation

I have done clustering for the MKMapView.

```swift
class BaseMKPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var index: Int!
}

class ClusteredAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Enable clustering by just setting the clusteringIdentifier
        clusteringIdentifier = "AnnotationView"
        // clusteringIdentifier = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()
        displayPriority = .defaultHigh
        glyphImage = Images.annotationIcon
    }
}

extension MKMapView {
    func animateToPoint(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, animated: Bool) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 250.0, longitudinalMeters: 250.0)
        self.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

So I have my ViewController. It crashes when collection view calls `mapViewAnimateTo`. Though it doesn't crash frequently but it does crash.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Method that will add annotations to the mapView.
    private func addAnnotation(_ i: Int, _ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let annotation = BaseMKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.index = i // Index to differentiate the annotation.
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }
        var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Pin")

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = ClusteredAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin")
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }

    // This method is called when horizontal collection view stops scrolling.
    func mapViewAnimateTo(_ index: Int) {

        // Gets the array of points
        let point = presenter.getCollectedPoints(index).coordinates

        // coordinate to animate.
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point[0].latitude, longitude: point[0].longitude)

        // animates to the coordinate
        /*********** Sometimes it crashes here. ***********/
        mapView.animateToPoint(coordinate, animated: true)

        for annotation in mapView.annotations {
            if annotation.coordinate.latitude == coordinate.latitude && annotation.coordinate.longitude == coordinate.longitude {
                // mark the annotation as selected.
                /*********** Sometimes it crashes here. ***********/
                mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes with the below report, how can I solve this crash. Here I have attached an image of the crash

[image]

```swift
2019-04-17 16:17:21.033478+0530 Demo App[13618:213851] -[Demo_App.BaseMKPointAnnotation memberAnnotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000007e2da0
2019-04-17 16:17:21.042907+0530 Demo App[13618:213851] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Demo_App.BaseMKPointAnnotation memberAnnotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000007e2da0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115c0a6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001151aeac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115c28ab4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115c0f443 ___forwarding___ + 1443
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115c11238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MapKit                              0x0000000116577298 -[MKMapView annotationContainer:requestAddingClusterForAnnotationViews:] + 168
    6   MapKit                              0x0000000116703e7c -[MKAnnotationContainerView _updateClusterableAnnotationViews:withID:] + 461
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115c7a9c2 -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 226
    8   MapKit                              0x00000001166ff3fc -[MKAnnotationContainerView updateAnnotationViewsForReason:] + 282
    9   MapKit                              0x0000000116702cbc -[MKAnnotationContainerView finishAddingAnnotationViews] + 29
    10  MapKit                              0x000000011657f59f -[MKMapView annotationManager:didAddAnnotationRepresentations:] + 53
    11  MapKit                              0x000000011663d24e -[MKAnnotationManager updateVisibleAnnotations] + 1660
    12  MapKit                              0x000000011656e238 -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:] + 208
    13  MapKit                              0x00000001165734a2 -[MKMapView mapLayer:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 67
    14  VectorKit                           0x000000012f00ae54 -[VKMapView map:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 122
    15  VectorKit                           0x000000012f089f6b __86-[VKMapCameraController _animateToPosition:pitch:yaw:duration:timingCurve:completion:]_block_invoke.227 + 75
    16  VectorKit                           0x000000012f042747 -[VKAnimation stopAnimation:] + 106
    17  VectorKit                           0x000000012f042b4c -[VKTimedAnimation stopAnimation:] + 44
    18  VectorKit                           0x000000012f042c2e -[VKTimedAnimation onTimerFired:] + 47
    19  VectorKit                           0x000000012efb0b24 _ZN2md16AnimationManager12onTimerFiredEd + 208
    20  VectorKit                           0x000000012efb1b60 _ZN2md27InteractiveAnimationManager12onTimerFiredEd + 14
    21  VectorKit                           0x000000012f26246c _ZN2md9MapEngine11layoutSceneEdb + 96
    22  VectorKit                           0x000000012f2623f6 -[_MapEngineRenderQueueSource renderQueueForTimestamp:] + 27
    23  VectorKit                           0x000000012f3212e7 -[MDDisplayLayer drawToTexture:withTimestamp:completionHandler:prepareHandler:] + 139
    24  VectorKit                           0x000000012f46224f __33-[GGLOpenGLESLayer onTimerFired:]_block_invoke + 87
    25  VectorKit                           0x000000012f469049 _ZN3ggl10OESContext17performWhileBoundEU13block_pointerFvvE + 163
    26  VectorKit                           0x000000012f462009 -[GGLOpenGLESLayer onTimerFired:] + 106
    27  VectorKit                           0x000000012f2642d3 _ZN2md9MapEngine11renderSceneEdNSt3__18functionIFvvEEE + 93
    28  VectorKit                           0x000000012f263f34 _ZN2md9MapEngine18onRenderTimerFiredEd + 188
    29  VectorKit                           0x000000012f464c4c _ZN3ggl11DisplayLink12onTimerFiredEd + 32
    30  VectorKit                           0x000000012f464b1b -[_GGLDisplayLinkTarget displayLinkFired:] + 81
    31  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112339d97 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 663
    32  QuartzCore                          0x00000001124084a2 _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 297
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b46096 __CFMachPortPerform + 150
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b72419 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b71a7b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 459
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b6c00a __CFRunLoopRun + 2490
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115b6b302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001197dc2fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    39  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120226ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    40  TOSCollect Live                     0x000000010f16200b main + 75
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117743541 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: hi, check the memory usage in debug navigator at run time. may be the crash is due to not deallocating memory in the case of using map view.

Comment: @BenRockey I check that issue first, It's not memory issue.

Comment: have you check by adding exception breakpoint.?

Comment: @BenRockey Yes sir, I tried.

Comment: can't find the exact issue. please check data is correctly passing on collection view change.

Comment: Thanks @BenRockey for your inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191991/discussion-between-anirudha-mahale-and-ben-rockey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming as I was selecting the annotation which wasn't visible on the map. I was cluttered.

I solved the issue by first zooming to the location and then setting the annotation property as selected.

So I updated the `mapViewAnimateTo` method.

```swift
func mapViewAnimateTo(_ index: Int) {
    print("MapView scrolling to index \(index)")
    let point = presenter.getCollectedPoints(index).coordinates
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point[0].latitude, longitude: point[0].longitude)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        // 2. Upon completion of zooming, marks the first annotation found at respective coordinate as selected.
        if let annotation = self.mapView.annotations.filter ({ $0.coordinate.latitude == coordinate.latitude && $0.coordinate.longitude == coordinate.longitude }).first {
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
        }
    })
    // 1. Zooms to the respective coordinate.
    mapView.animateToPoint(coordinate, animated: true)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Even updated the distance of the region to 10 meters.

```swift
extension MKMapView {
    func animateToPoint(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, animated: Bool) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10, longitudinalMeters: 10)
        self.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: animated)
    }
}
```